# Content Dialog with rounded corner [UWP Win10 Build 1904*]

Tags: uwp, dialog, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app. For some reason I have to show something in Content Dialog. I want set a corner radius value to Content Dialog. But adding corner radius value, there is a extra shadow in the all corner. How to fix that?

My Content Dialog :

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="SampleApp.SampleDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SampleApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TITLE"
    PrimaryButtonText="Button1"
    SecondaryButtonText="Button2"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
    CornerRadius="50">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

[Output of Content Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nSVH.png)

Answer (score 1):

[The official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/depth-shadow#themeshadow-in-popups) mentions “ThemeShadow automatically casts shadows when applied to any XAML element in a Popup. It will cast shadows on the app background content behind it and any other open Popups below it.” Therefore, one workaround is to elevate the element from other elements behind it by using the z component of the Translation property like the following.

Also, this is an interesting question, we have reported this issue to the team.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       
        SampleDialog dialog = new SampleDialog();
        dialog.Translation += new Vector3(0, 0, -100);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Besides, it seems that you’re using the custom ContentDialog. If you want to add the default ContentDialog, more info could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-20348#examples).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this `Setter` to the ContentDialog's `Style` code, which modifies the drop shadow property:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentDialog">
    <Setter Property="IsDefaultShadowEnabled" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

Also I don't recommend using more than an 8px `CornerRadius`, as it goes against the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/signature-experiences/geometry#rounded-corners) and looks pretty out of place, but whatever.